# Add custom (structured) metadata to scenarios

Tags: gherkin, python-behave

In our Behave-based BDD tests we see a need to add some metadata to the scenarios (for the purpose of test reports). The data is in the form of key/value pairs with a handful of keys and values are typically numbers. The structure will be parsed by our custom test report generator during and/or after the test run.

Is there a canonical way to do this in Gherkin? We considered adding them to the text of the scenario itself, e.g.

```
Scenario: Some scenario (somekey=42)
  When ...
```

Behave also supports tags

```
@sometag(42)
Scenario: Some scenario
  When ...
```

but since tags have side effects (test selection), this seems messy. Another option we have is to do e.g.

```
@sometag(42)
Scenario: Some scenario
  Given something
   When something
   Then assert
   Then report somekey 42
```

but no solution feels "clean". Is there a canoncal way in Gherkin to accomplish what we are trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to integrate your BDD tests with an external system of some sort?

Comment: I do not see a canonical way of doing this with gherkin/cucumber. You are basically left with tags or comments for meta data. Unless you want to go the really complicated route of having Foo.feature and Foo.feature.meta and doing something custom with that file.

Comment: Can you give more info about what kind of meta data you want?

Comment: Key value pairs, in this case the value is a number or a string. For the ”somekey” above, I want to use this value in my custom test report generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no canonical way to associate meta data with scenarios or features. The closest thing you have is tags. There is nothing particularly wrong with using tags. Sure you can filter your tests by tags, but that doesn't mean you cannot make up your own tag format for meta data. You can do additional processing in a before or after scenario callback/hook.

If you do not need to do any processing during a test run, you can always use comments and then make up your own format. You can write a script to parse the comments in the feature files in a custom script, if you want. I'm sure as long as you are consistent it should be fine.

---

Gherkin language reference: https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#keywords

Comment: Serenity seems to have adopted a custom cucumber tag format, by using tag prefixes such as `@issue` and `@issues` and then combining these with a `:` and the value, following it. No spaces allowed, it seems. Example:

`@issues:ISSUE-456,ISSUE-001`

https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/serenity-issues.html#_linking_with_issues_for_cucumber